# Difference between android:hint and android:autofillHints in EditText

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, hint

I am unable to understand if there is any difference between

`android:hint`

and

`android:autofillHints`

in `EditText`

I have the following code -

```
android:hint="@string/enter_name"
android:autofillHints="@string/enter_name"
```

What is the difference here in the two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:hint` is more like a placeholder that sort of explains what type of input the `EditText` is asking for. i.e. If an `EditText` is asking for posting a status on social media, the hint like **What's on your mind?** will be suitable.
[image]

`android:autofillHints` is to give actual values to the user to input in the `EditText`. Much like simulating a task for the user to think of a value to put inside the input field. The `Autofill` process requires more steps though as you also need to consider many things, like formatting the date.
[image]

Comment: Can I have both together?

Comment: Well honestly I haven't tried both together but Yes you can have both since `hint` is just a placeholder, its sole purpose is to give idea to user about input.

Comment: Yes you can have both together

Answer (score 1):

**android:hint** means Hint text to display when the text is empty.

**android:autofillHints** means it describes the content of a view so that a autofill service can fill in the appropriate
data. Multiple hints can be combined in a comma separated list or an array of strings
to mean e.g. emailAddress or postalAddress.
To know more about autofill service see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services)